# How to remove the smallest element in a Binary Search Tree in python?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

Using recursion, I am asked to create a method for removing the smallest element of a BST in Python. I cannot use the already implemented function *remove*. Have tried several times with similar codes, even copying and editing the *remove* function. However, the smallest node it is not removed.

Can anyone help me with this?

Knowing that the original tree has no self.parent node, just self.elem, self.right and self.left I have try several things. However, I will show the one that I don't understand why the code is not working.

```
# this method is used for removing the smallest value in the tree
def removeSmallest(self):
    return self._removeSmallest(self._root)

def _removeSmallest(self, node):
    if node is None:
        return 0
    while node.left is not None:
        node = node.left
    return node
```

Following the code of my *remove* function, which used the return *node* in order to delete that node, I don't understand why this doesn't work. Notice that I have implemented a code for knowing the minimum element (that works). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

- `return 0` is not advised: it is better to return `None` when there is nothing to delete. This can be useful in recursive calls (read on)
- When your `while` loop finishes, you are *at* the node that must be deleted, but you then need to still set the `left` attribute of the parent, while you have lost the reference to that node. You can solve this with recursion.
- There is no provision in your code to alter the `_root` reference. Yet, it could well be that the root of the tree has the smallest value (when it has no `left` child.

You could use the idea you had to return a node instance, but don't return the node that needs to be deleted, but the node that should moved upwards to take its place (if any) or `None`. Then the *caller* of the function can use the returned node instance to attach it to the parent node that it still has.

Here is how it can work:

```
    def removeSmallest(self):
        if self._root:
            self._root = self._removeSmallest(self._root)
    
    def _removeSmallest(self, node):
        if node.left:
            node.left = self._removeSmallest(node.left)
            return node
        else:
            return node.right
```